# Zend Tool CLI always creates index action index view

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line, zend-tool

I have the following problem with Zend tool (component of Zend Framework)

When I give the command to create a controller without a index action the action is still created. I use the following command:

```
zf create controller auth 0
```

Is this the wrong command or is there a problem with zend tool.

I use version 10.6 of Zend Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command looks to be correct:
`zf create controller $name $indexActionIncluded`
I can reproduce the issue and I've tried every conceivable argument for `indexActionIncluded` to no avail. So yeah, looks like a bug.